# Is it possible to "bind" sp_executesql to the calling procedure, as recorded in the Query Store?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

Statements executed with `sp_executesql` appear to be generally "unbound" from the procedure in which they appear. By "bind", I simply mean "associated to the calling object".

The goal is to make it simpler to associate statements in the Query Store:

```
select object_name(q.object_id) as [Statement Context]
from sys.query_store_query q
where 1=1
    and object_name(q.object_id) like 'This will be the procedure name for ''normal'' statements'
```

While it's possible to embed comments in the statements that will show up in the `query_sql_text`, this feels a bit extra-hackish.

Also, it seems that `sp_executesql` would *need* some form of context binding as the dynamic SQL can access non-global temp tables in the surrounding scope: without a binding, how can SQL Server ensure the validity & stability of the temp table schema in the created plans?

Comment: For the last paragraph, see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/reduced-recompilations-for-workloads-using-temporary-tables/ba-p/388391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that embedding comments is currently the best way to distinguish different pieces of dynamic SQL when viewed from Query Store / Extended events / Trace - unfortunately.

I've had plenty of runtime errors with dynamic sql & temp tables so I don't think it does ENSURE temp table validity & stability.

You can use @@nestlevel to see how many SPs / functions are currently in the call stack, but I think you want more information than that. You can use error_procedure() - but only in a catch block, sounds like what you want is Microsoft to add a function current_procedure() or calling_procedure() that will tell you the name of either the current routine or the routine that called this one - maybe add a request here ? :- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server